# Expectation and Variance of the sequence $HHH$ in $n$ tosses

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

> Toss a fair coin $n \ge 5$ times, and let $X$ be the number of occurrences
> of the pattern $HHH$ in the sequence of tosses. For example, if
> $n = 9$ and the outcome is $\omega = HHTHHHHTH$ then $X(\omega) = 2$.
> Compute E[$X$] and Var ($X$).

My idea so far is to start with $n=5$, where there are three possible outcomes that give us at least three consecutive heads, namely $HHHTT,THHHT,TTHHH,HHHHT,THHHH,HHHHH$, in the first three outcomes we get $X(\omega)=1$, in the third and fourth outcomes we get $X(\omega)=2$, and for the final outcome we get $X(\omega)=3$.

When we move on to $n=6$ and assess all outcomes we get $4$ occurrences of $X(\omega)=1$, $3$ occurrences of $X(\omega)=2$, $2$ occurrences of $X(\omega)=3$, and $1$ occurrence of $X(\omega)=4$.

I don't know exactly what to do with this information or if I'm going in the right direction, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicator random variables are your friend here. There are $n-2$ windows of three tosses in the sequence, and each window has a $\frac18$ chance to come up $HHH$ (i.e. we consider each window as a random variable, and these add to make $X$). Therefore the expected value of $X$ is $\frac{n-2}8$.

For the variance of $X$ we sum up the following:

- Variance of each window: $n-2$ times $\frac18×\frac78$, or $\frac7{64}(n-2)$
- Covariance of windows one toss apart: twice $n-3$ times $\frac1{16}-\frac1{8^2}$, or $\frac6{64}(n-3)$
- Covariance of windows two tosses apart: twice $n-4$ times
  $\frac1{32}-\frac1{8^2}$, or $\frac2{64}(n-4)$

Thus the variance of $X$ is
$$\frac1{64}(7(n-2)+6(n-3)+2(n-4))=\frac{15n-40}{64}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your explanation for the expectation, but I'm not quite grasping where the variance is coming from. Could you walk me through this section of your answer? We were taught that variance is $E[X^{2}]-E[X]^{2}$ when $E[X^{2}]<\infty$

Comment: @KarlCoogan The variance of a sum of random variables is sum of their _pairwise covariances_. The covariance between two variables $X,Y$ is $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, so you see that the covariance of $X$ with itself is just the normal variance. If two variables are independent their covariance is zero.

Comment: And do these variances still hold for some general number of tosses $n$ or does this only hold for $n=5$?

Comment: @KarlCoogan they hold for all $n\ge5$, as per the question.